# java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Tags: android

I am getting this error .Although I have gone through various link but nothing helped.
Already using `getChildFragmentManager()` as mentioned in various links.
This is the code:

```
viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0: return new Fragment1();
            case 1: return new UserFragment();
            case 2: return new Fragment2();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: show code with logcat

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @S.Verma Were you able to solve this ?